# Одноразовая функция python

Tags: python, функции, lambda

Есть небольшой код, который записывает данные в `config`

```
user = input('Введите Логин в такой форме "example" - ')
password = input('Введите пароль в таком же формате "example"')

f = open('config_act.py', 'w', encoding='utf8')
f.write(f"user = {user}\npassword = {password}")
f.close()
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы эта функция вызывалась при первом запуске кода, и при последующих запусках не вызывалась. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну например в следующий раз попытаться открыть этот файл на чтение. Если он есть, то это уже повторный запуск:

```
try:
    with open('config_act.py', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        user, password = f.readlines()
except:
    user = input('Введите Логин в такой форме "example" - ')
    password = input('Введите пароль в таком же формате "example"')
    with open('config_act.py', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
        f.write(f"user = {user}\npassword = {password}")
```